# How to call javascript function in ZK

Tags: javascript, zk

In ZK framework, inside zul file i want to call javascript function but it does not happens.

```
<a label="Click" onClick="popUp();">
```

I have that popUp() function also. But when I click on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createPopUp(url)
    {
        var w = 600;
        var h = 500;
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        window.open(url,'name','scrollbars=yes,width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    }
</script>
```

But when I click on that link it dispalys following error:

```
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` popUp();'' : 
Command not found: popUp() : at Line: 13 : 
in file: inline evaluation of: `` popUp();'' : popUp ( )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, if you want to achieve this in java, rather than .zul file, you can use

```
label.setWidgetListener(Events.ON_CLICK, "popUp();");
```

as indicated [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Event_Listening) with [javadoc](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Component.html#setWidgetListener%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem I found below way:

```
<a label="Click" xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client" w:onClick="createPopUp('http://www.facebook.com/prabhatsubedi');"/>
```

Comment: BTW you can use a shortcut like `xmlns:w="client"` instead of complete url

Comment: btw, you asked question, answered it, accepted it, thank yourself and respond your thank. Your problem is bigger than javascript i think :)

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, it's also possible to call Javascript code from the server side using `Clients.evalJavaScript`. So you would place it in an event listener.

##### Example

Java:

```
@Command
public void createPopUp() {
    Clients.evalJavaScript("createPopUp('http://www.facebook.com/prabhatsubedi');");
}
```

Zul:

```
<a label="Click" onClick="@command('createPopUp')">
```

##### Addendum to @Narayan-Subedi's answer

You can declare the client namespace once at the top of your file and use it multiple times:

```
<zk xmlns:n="native" xmlns:c="client">
    <a label="Click" c:onClick="createPopUp('http://www.facebook.com/prabhatsubedi');"/>
</zk>
```